# Distribution of ratio of 2 non-standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I know that the ratio of 2 standard normal RVs has a standard Cauchy distribution.

I have data from $X_1, ..., X_5$ and $Y_1, ..., Y_5$, all independent and normal with non-zero means and non-one variances. I want the distribution of $R = \bar{X} \div \bar{Y}$. It seems to me that the first step is to get the distribution of $R$.

$\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are not standardized, so what is the distribution of their ratio?

Of course, if there is a way to "standardize" $R$ so that it has a Cauchy distribution, please show me how.

Comment: Assuming everything is independent, the standard deviations (if positive) and averages can be handled by scaling, and the interesting question is the distribution of $\frac{X}{Y}$ with $X\sim N{\mu_X,1}$ and $Y\sim N{\mu_Y,1}$

Comment: Some experimentation suggests the distribution of this non-central ratio may not always be unimodal

Comment: @Henry Yes, the variables are independent; I have revised my question to state this. Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "handled by scaling"?

Comment: If $X_i \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma^2_X)$ and $Y_j \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$ then $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sigma_X} \bar X \sim N\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sigma_X}\mu_X,1\right)$ and similarly with $\bar Y$ so $R$ is a rescaled version of the ratio of these

Comment: @Henry Ah, OK. Cancelling the $\sqrt{5}$ in the ratio, there is now a scaling factor of $\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}$ in front of the R. Now that we have a variance of 1 for $X$ and $Y$, what can we say about the distribution of $R$?

Comment: That is the interesting question, and I do not know.  You can certainly say $R$ does not have a mean.  Looking empirically at $\mu_X=2, \mu_Y=1$ with unit standard deviations where you might naively and wrongly guess the centre of the distribution could be near $2$, it seems the median of $\frac{X}{Y}$ is about $1.33$ and the mode near $1$, while the density near $-0.7$ seems to be less than near $-1.7$ and $0$.

Comment: I don't think the distribution has a special name other than "ratio of non-central normal random variables". It is however possible to derive a formula for the pdf. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uncorrelated_noncentral_normal_ratio

Comment: I have edited my question to specify that I seek the confidence interval, not the distribution. Thanks for your patience while I clarified exactly what I want.

Comment: The confidence interval for what parameter?

Comment: Also the distribution of $R$ has no well defined moments. In fact, $\bar R_n=\frac 1 1\sum_{k=1}^nR_k$ will converge in distribution towards the Cauchy distribution...not the normal as CLT suggests.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson - I want the confidence interval of R. I know that the Cauchy distribution has no defined moments, but I can always calculate the sample mean and sample standard deviation to calculate the confidence interval. It is bell-shaped, so the procedure should be just like the normal distribution. Am I wrong to think like this?

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Ah, that Wikipedia article section LOOKS like very promising! Thank you! I will now use the invariance principle to swap those mu's and sigma's with x-bars and s-squares, and then I will use them to get the confidence interval for R.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Upon reflection, you are correct, and I was mistaken. I have changed my title as you suggested.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Your link has the answer. Would you like to write it as a solution, so that I can mark it as correct and give you credit?